# IBOutlet pageControl is invalid

Tags: swift, io, uicollectionview, iboutlet, uipagecontrol

I trying to add **pageControl** in **viewController** for display **current page** and **total pages**.

I have **collectionView** inside **viewController**. But if i add **@IBOutlet** in **viewController** i get the **error**:

**"The pageControl outlet from the DetailViewController to the UIPageControl is invalid. Outlet cannot be connected to repeating content."**

That means repeating content?

I understand that this question has been asked many times, but I tried what was suggested but nothing helped.

PageControl in main.storyboard have only one @IBOutlet and it throws an error...
[image: pageControl]

If need my code, he is here:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - IBOutlet's
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var hallImages: Hall?

    var currentPage = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 626
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }
    // MARK: - CollectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let imagesHall = hallImages?.ImagesHalls.count else {
            return 0
        }
        return imagesHall
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCollectionViewCell

        if let imagesHalls = hallImages?.ImagesHalls[indexPath.item] {
            cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagesHalls))
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

How i can add pageControll in collectionView or collectionCell (i don't know how is better)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It is because your page control is a subview of the cell. You cannot do this.

1. take it out of your cell
2. put it in your main view/ safe area